# Simple Column split in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have something like this in a CSV:

```
 phone                            name     area
 (444) 444-4444, (000) 000-0000   Foo      cityname, ST
 (555) 555-5555                   Bar      othercity, SN
```

How would I arrive at this most simply:

```
 phone            name     area       State
 (444) 444-4444   Foo      cityname   ST
 (555) 555-5555   Bar      othercity  SN
```

It's two basic splits - in the first, I want to get rid of everything past the first index from ['phone'], but in the second, I want to add everything after the comma from ['area'] into ['State'] - I figured it would be great to learn both methods.

In the actual file, the CSV is split with commas and fields use quotation marks: it's a standard csv.  I used the whitespace table to show the problem.

Comment: That's a tricky parse task, and this [seems to] is **not a csv**. You have to have tabs in your file or your phone, name and area values have to be aligned, to be able correctly parse it in general case.

Comment: I think this question would be clearer if you indicated which entries in the file are separated by spaces and which are separated by tabs, maybe using `\t` for each tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
#df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', dtype={'area': str, 'phone': str})
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['phone','name','area'],
                data=[['(444) 444-4444, (000) 000-0000', 'Foo', 'cityname, ST'],
                      ['(555) 555-5555',   'Bar', 'othercity, SN']])
print df
df['State'] = df.area.apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[1] if len(x.split(','))>1 else '')
df.area = df.area.apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[0])
df.phone = df.phone.apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[0])
print df
```

Out:

```
                            phone name           area
0  (444) 444-4444, (000) 000-0000  Foo   cityname, ST
1                  (555) 555-5555  Bar  othercity, SN
            phone name       area State
0  (444) 444-4444  Foo   cityname    ST
1  (555) 555-5555  Bar  othercity    SN
```

Comment: With [1] I get list index out of range.  With [0] I get float object has no attribute split (It's a large file, but I don't know why anything in that column would have the float attribute).

Comment: I get a list index out of range error.  I assume this is the result of some area entries not having the comma and state name.  In this case, how do I avoid the error?

Comment: Strangely, I have a case where I get "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'" even though I used dtype = np.object on that column, and the dtype was confirmed by print(mytable.dtypes). When a cell has a zero-length string, it reports print(type(cell)) => <type 'float'> and the cell value is NaN.